# Pandas Merge - Bring in identical columnvalues based on keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 3 dataframes like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [2, 4], [3,6], [4,12], [5,18]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [2, 6], [3,9]], columns=['A', 'C'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 15, "hello"], [5, 19, "yes"]], columns=['A', 'C', 'D'])
```

They look like this,
df

```
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   4
2   3   6
3   4   12
4   5   18
```

df2

```
    A   C
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   9
```

df3

```
   A    C   D
0   4   15  hello
1   5   19  yes
```

my merges, first merge,

```
f_merge = pd.merge(df, df2, on='A',how='left')
```

second merge,(`first_merge` with `df3`)

```
s_merge = pd.merge(f_merge, df3, on='A', how='left')
```

I get the output like this,

```
    A   B   C_x  C_y       D
0   1   3   5.0  NaN      NaN
1   2   4   6.0  NaN      NaN
2   3   6   9.0  NaN      NaN
3   4   12  NaN  15.0     hello
4   5   18  NaN  19.0     yes
```

I need like this,

```
    A   B   C        D
0   1   3   5.0     NaN
1   2   4   6.0     NaN
2   3   6   9.0     NaN
3   4   12  15.0    hello
4   5   18  19.0    yes
```

How can I achieve this output? Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat df2 and df3 before merging.

```
new_df = pd.merge(df, pd.concat([df2, df3], ignore_index=True), on='A')

new_df

Out: 
   A   B   C      D
0  1   3   5    NaN
1  2   4   6    NaN
2  3   6   9    NaN
3  4  12  15  hello
4  5  18  19    yes
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do `combine_first`

```
df.set_index('A',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('A').combine_first(df).combine_first(df3.set_index('A'))
      B     C      D
A                   
1   3.0   5.0    NaN
2   4.0   6.0    NaN
3   6.0   9.0    NaN
4  12.0  15.0  hello
5  18.0  19.0    yes
```